# Select count from second table based on initial select

Tags: t-sql, select

Table 1:
AccountId, ReferenceId, Name, (lots of other columns)

Table 2:
AccountId, ReferenceId, (other columns)

How can I do a select to get the following:

```
AccountId, ReferenceId, [Count(*) in Table2 where accountId and reference ID match.]
1, AB, 1
1, AC, 0
2, AD, 4
2, EF, 0
```

etc

Guessing a join, but that gives me values, not a count?
Tried adding a count, but get errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT t1.AccountId, t1.ReferenceId, COUNT(t2.AccountId)
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.AccountId = t2.AccountId AND
                       t1.ReferenceId = t2.ReferenceId
GROUP BY t1.AccountId, t1.ReferenceId
```

should work. The trick is to group by both key values so you can aggregate over other values. In this case you want to simply count values from other rows (you could also sum or average values from the grouped-by rows.).

Comment: You would need an `OUTER` join to return those for which the count is zero.

Comment: You should use a `LEFT JOIN` for what the OP asked, a `JOIN` doesn't give the right results

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT T1.AccountId,
       T1.ReferenceId,
       COUNT(T2.ReferenceId) AS Cnt
FROM   Table1 T1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
         ON T1.AccountId = T2.AccountId
            AND T1.ReferenceId = T2.ReferenceId
GROUP  BY T1.AccountId,
          T1.ReferenceId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.AccountId, t1.ReferenceId, COUNT(t2.AccountId)
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
ON (t1.AccountId=t2.AccountId AND t1.ReferenceId=t2.ReferenceId)
GROUP BY Table1.AccountId, Table1.ReferenceId
```

Comment: This filters the results of Table1 that don't have a match on table2, it should be a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Also I don't think `COUNT(t2.*)` is valid syntax

Comment: @Martin it is valid; I use it frequently.

Comment: I'll rephrase. I **know** that it isn't valid syntax. Try `select status,COUNT(t2.*) from master..spt_values join sys.objects t2 on number=object_id group by status` gives `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: gah you're right @Martin I should've paid closer attention to the `tsql` tag.

Comment: Martin is right I have tested it with my sample data (by changing table names) and it give me syntax error.

Comment: @Muhammad it's not valid in MSSQL or MySQL, which are the only two I use. I was working too quickly in my initial response and didn't look at it a second time until @Martin put in his sample query and I saw `t2.*`...

Answer (score 0):

sample data

```
declare @tbl1 table (AccountId INT, ReferenceId int, Name varchar(20))
declare @tbl2 table (AccountId INT, ReferenceId int)

insert into @tbl1 select 1, 10, 'White'
insert into @tbl1 select 2, 20, 'Green'
insert into @tbl1 select 3, 30, 'Black'
insert into @tbl1 select 3, 40, 'Red'

insert into @tbl2 select 1, 10
insert into @tbl2 select 1, 10
insert into @tbl2 select 2, 20
insert into @tbl2 select 3, 30
```

Query

```
select t.AccountId, t.ReferenceId, t.Name
    ,(select COUNT(*) from @tbl2 t2 
            where t.AccountId = t2.AccountId 
            and t.ReferenceId = t.ReferenceId) as countt

    from @tbl1 t
```

Comment: Why would you use a subquery unnecessarily?

Comment: @Brian you are right. Just to give a different approach but not good. Answers with LEFT JOIN and Group BY are better.